# How to fix httpd error code AH00526?

Tags: networking, apache-httpd, webserver

Hey new to linux here and I just got Centos 7.2 up and running on my pc. I was following along on "The Perfect Server" instructions and got all the way to installing apache and now I'm stuck at configuring ispconfig because my machine returns an error when I run command `systemctl restart  httpd.service.` It states job for httpd service failed because the control process exited with error code AH00526.

```
Oct 25 05:37:49 server01.tcforwarding.com httpd[14691]: [Tue Oct 25 05:37:49.091640 2016] [alias:warn] [pid 14691] AH00671: The ScriptAlias directive in /etc/httpd/conf.d/mailman.conf at line 6 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier ScriptAlias.
Oct 25 05:37:49 server01.tcforwarding.com httpd[14691]: AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:356
Oct 25 05:37:49 server01.tcforwarding.com httpd[14691]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 6 of /etc/httpd/conf/sites-enabled/000-ispconfig.vhost:
Oct 25 05:37:49 server01.tcforwarding.com httpd[14691]: Port must be specified
Oct 25 05:37:49 server01.tcforwarding.com systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 25 05:37:49 server01.tcforwarding.com kill[14699]: kill: cannot find process "" 
Oct 25 05:37:49 server01.tcforwarding.com systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1 
Oct 25 05:37:49 server01.tcforwarding.com systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server. 
Oct 25 05:37:49 server01.tcforwarding.com systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state. 
Oct 25 05:37:49 server01.tcforwarding.com systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

Here's part of the vhost file itself.

```
_
__Listen root
NameVirtualHost *:root
_
VirtualHost default:root *:80
_ServerAdmin webmaster@tcforwarding.com
_
__Directory /var/www/ispconfig/
____FilesMatch ".ph(p3?|tml)$"
```

Let me know if you need anything else!

Answer (score 1):

`root` is not a valid TCP port number.  You may want something like:

```
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost *:80
```